# Detect when browser back button is pressed - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, browser

How can I detect when back button on browser (Chrome, FireFox, Safari etc.) is clicked through JavaScript on my React website and take actions accordingly?

Also, when back button on mobile is pressed, is the event same or similar to when back button in browser is clicked?

Looking forward for an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you going back to somewhere on your own site?  There isn't a lot you can actually do here.

Comment: Currently the back button takes me to the previous window, I instead want to do something on my site.

Comment: That would be a huge security risk. You won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple custom hook for that:

```
const useBackButton = () => {
  const [isBack, setIsBack] = useState(false);
  const handleEvent = () => {
    setIsBack(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", handleEvent);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleEvent);
  });

  return isBack;
};
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-borg-5qwl3?file=/src/index.js

Objective approach:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isBack: false
    };
    this.onPopstate = this.onPopstate.bind(this)
  }

  onPopstate() {
    this.setState({ isBack: true });
    alert("back!!!");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", this.onPopstate);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("popstate", this.onPopstate, false);
  }
```

Comment: I tried adding this in `componentDidMount` but it doesn't work - ```window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
      this.setState({ isBack: true });
      alert("back!!!");
});                                                                                                                                      
 ```

Comment: ```class BasicExampleClass extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isBack: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
      this.setState({ isBack: true });
      alert("back!!!");
    });
  }
}```
I think it works fine. I've updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-borg-5qwl3?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Does this work in Chrome? I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, I tested it on Chromium 90.0.4430.93

Answer (score 1):

Add these 2 lines into your componentDidMount().This worked for me

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
   window.location.replace(`YOUR URL`);
});
```

Comment: Work smoothly!!!

Answer (score 0):

This works some of the time, but there's no reliable way to detect stuff like this, as of now.

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(){
//Checking if the user hasn't clicked on something on the page
if(document.activeElement==document.querySelector("body")){console.log("Back Button Maybe?")}
})
```

Comment: should this be in `componentDidMount()` ?

Comment: What is `componentDidMount`? You can just paste this in your `js` file

Comment: [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is a react lifecycle method.